# Get user's facebook posts on friends' wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am currently making a Facebook canvas app using Django and Python for Facebook. To be able to make my app I need to retrieve the posts the user have made to his friends' walls. This has  proven to be a challenge.

I have tried using the connection user.posts with the graph API like this:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
posts = graph.get_connections('me', 'posts' , limit=5000)
```

Which in the graph explorer would be something like:

```
graph.facebook.com/me/posts
```

The post objects from this request does however not return any posts from the user on his friend's walls.

I also tried an FQL query which didn't return anything, at least not with myself as the user:

```
SELECT actor_id, message, post_id, source_id, tagged_ids, type
FROM stream WHERE type=56 AND source_id IN (SELECT user_1 FROM friend WHERE user_2=me())
```

I'm pretty sure that I could get what I wanted if I did a request for each friend separately but that would be too time consuming to be efficiently implemented. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this in one or two calls?